# Phonegap on Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode, macos, apache, cordova

Is it possible to install latest Phonegap on 10.6.8? In the requirements section it says, Apache Cordova needs at least Lion. Is it worth trying to intall legacy versions of Xcode & Phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can Take The Following [Tutorial](http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/installing-phonegap-1-0-into-xcode-4-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/) for that